# Excel VBA Search And Delete

Tags: excel, vba

So I use 1dcutx program which shoots out spread sheets with information. At the moment I have it deleting some cells and shifting them up and then renaming the page. Some stuff changes location like it is not the same for every spread sheet. So what I need left is a way to search and Delete that cell and also in some cases the cell to the left of it as well.

Example: 
Utilization, %:  Is in one cell
62.74 Would be right next to but this amount changes.

So I would need a search and delete and have it select the cell to the left and delete that one as well.

Here is what i have so far

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Sheets("1D_report").Select
    Rows("3:9").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("E1:F2").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Columns("H:H").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Sheets("1D_report").Select
    Sheets("1D_report").Name = "s_report"
End Sub
```

Comment: Tip: don't use macro recorder for anything other than learning how to do something through the Excel object model. Using it for actual "production" code is messy at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub asdf()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Cells.Find(What:="Utilization, %", After:=Range("A1"))
    Range(r, r.Offset(0, 1)).Clear
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to clear the cell to the LEFT of the found cell, use:

Offset(0,-1)

instead of:

Offset(0,1)

**EDIT2:**

I like several short macros rather than long ones
so I would use something like:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Call Macro1
    Call asdf
End Sub
```

**EDIT3:**

Try this version - do you get the error message??

```
Sub asdf()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim s As String
    s = "Utilization, %"
    Set r = Cells.Find(What:=s, After:=Range("A1"))
    If r Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox s & " could not be found" & vbCrLf & "I'am going on break"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Range(r, r.Offset(0, 1)).Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: What would it be like if I put it all together

Comment: Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: This error means it could not find the Utilization cell.  Expected if you ran the macro twice.

Comment: I didn't run it twice though do you have team viewer or something or able to contact me i really need to get this done soon

Comment: haha Thanks you think you could help me finish this program =D you are good with Vba

Comment: Not possible.......I am done for the night..... am on travel starting tomorrow......Will be back Thursday